# How can set counts on tabs?

Tags: android, android-tabs

There are 4 tabs in my app and i want to show my notification count on one of them tab i.e. Notification Tab. Can anyone help me that how i should do this. It will be very helpful for me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Check: [Badge on Android TabHost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292679/badge-on-android-tabhost)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16360564/1939564

Comment: Thnk u guys. It is really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the badge using the `BadgeView` class Which is already given [HERE](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger/blob/master/src/com/readystatesoftware/viewbadger/BadgeView.java). Copy the class in your application and use it as below:

```
private BadgeView badge1;
private TabWidget m_tabs;

m_tabs = (TabWidget) findViewById(android.R.id.tabs);
badge1 = new BadgeView(this, m_tabs, 0);
badge1.setText("5");
badge1.show();
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thnks frnd. It is really helpful.